Jetson Nano B01 Development Kit connection with industrial grade SIM7600G-H 4G DTU gsm module
I am currently working on the Jetson Nano B01 Development Kit. I am using SIM7600G-H 4G DTU Module to transfer data packets directly to an AWS S3 Bucket. I am powering the SIM7600G-H 4G DTU Module with the Jetson Nano and I'm seeing the power LED turn on and Tx & Rx LED also turn on.
I am receiving the following errors:
SIM7600G-H 4G DTU Module is not being detected on the Jetson Nano when I am connecting it with the USB cable.
The "lsusb" command does not detect the SIM7600G-H 4G DTU Module.
I have installed the SIM7600 Driver provided on the official site, but upon running the make command the following error message is received:
rm -rf *.o ~ core .depend ..cmd *.ko .mod.c .tmp_versions Module. modules.order make -C /lib/modules/4.9.337-tegra/build M=/home/bfa1/ILDS/SIM7600G-4G_DTU/Linux Driver/SIM7600_NDIS modules make[1]:
Entering directory ‘/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.337-tegra-ubuntu18.04_aarch64/kernel-4.9’ make[1]: 
*** No rule to make target ‘Driver/SIM7600_NDIS’. Stop. make[1]: 
Leaving directory ‘/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.337-tegra-ubuntu18.04_aarch64/kernel-4.9’ Makefile:8: recipe for target ‘all’ failed make:
*** [all] Error 2

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is really a question for the maker of the target device. I do notice that the driver is targeted at Ubuntu 18.04 which is end of life, no longer supported and out of scope of this site. You would need to match both the OS version and the kernel version (obtained with command 'uname -r') to have a chance of a successful build. You might like to append these to your question.
